# Are microwaves sinusoidal or is that just a model?

Tags: waves, electromagnetic-radiation, microwaves

I know that projectiles are parabolas because I can derive that from constant acceleration.  And the height of a Ferris wheel rider vs. time is demonstrably a sine wave.  What is the underlying thing that tells us microwaves are sinusoidal vs. some other periodic shape?    I'm teaching trig.

Comment: Do you mean electromagnetic frequencies in the GHz range, or the machines that heat up our tacos?

Comment: Who says that microwaves are sine waves? Any microwave signal that is modulated with information is, in fact, _not_ a sine wave. But sine waves are interesting because any periodic function can be expressed as an infinite sum of sines and cosines, and that fact enables powerful mathematical techniques for analyzing signals and periodic motions.

Comment: Beth, please elaborate.  You're teaching trig at the high school level?  How is the mathematical function of a microwave related to this?

Comment: Microwaves can be sinusoidal but don’t have to be.

Comment: @SolomonSlow That's an answer. You should post it.

Comment: *But sine waves are interesting because any periodic function can be expressed as an infinite sum of sines and cosines, and that fact enables powerful mathematical techniques for analyzing signals and periodic motions.* Other families of functions exist that have the same properties. What's special about sine waves compared to other periodic functions is that when you add two sine waves having the same period, you get another sine wave.

Comment: You mobile phone uses microwaves to transmit your call. If they could only be sinusoidal the calls wouldnt be very interesting

Answer (score -5):

The wave equation for light tells us that solutions are sinusoidal:

$$ \frac{\partial^2 E}{\partial t^2} = c^2\frac{\partial^2 E}{\partial x^2}$$

(here, in one dimensions with the electric field $E(x, t)$ a function of position $x$ and time $t$).

If you guess a sinusoidal solution:

$$ E(x, t) = e^{i(kx-\omega t+\phi)}$$

(note:

$$e^{i(kx-\omega t+\phi)} = \cos{(kx-\omega t+\phi)}+i\sin{(kx-\omega t+\phi)} $$

is the most general solution that is sinusoidal in space and time)

and plug it in, you get:

$$ -\omega^2E(x, t) = -c^2k^2E(x, t)  $$

which means:

$$ \omega = ck =2\pi c/\lambda $$

is the relation between frequency and wavelength ($\lambda = 2\pi/k$).

Hence you can specify *a* *solution* by its frequency $\omega$.

This represents and infinitely long wave with infinite duration. In the real world, boundary conditions matter, so this is not the actual solution. Nevertheless, the machinery of Fourier analysis allows us to build any solution, periodic or not, as a superposition of different frequencies.

Comment: "The wave equation for light tells us that solutions are sinusoidal."  Absolutely not!  For the pure wave equation without any added dispersive terms, disturbances of *any* shape are allowed.  The general one-dimensional solution is $E(x,t)=f(x-ct)+g(x-ct)$, where $f$ and $g$ are *any* (suitably smooth) functions.

Comment: One of the arguments should be $(x+ct)$, otherwise I agree.

Comment: I am at 10,500' feet, straight from sea level. Sorry.

Comment: @Buzz did you read the "allows us to build any solution, periodic or not, as a superposition of different frequencies." part?